# Corona FPS stutter

Tags: coronasdk, frame-rate

I am developing an application using corona, but I'm having a problem where moving an object across the screen at a steady pace will cause it to stutter.

It seems like the problem is more visible when running at 60 FPS.
If you want to see the problem, here is an example:

http://sharesend.com/i3dwb

We have tested on:

- Windows simulator
- Mac simulator
- galaxy s hardware

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I can see nothing wrong with the code. This is probably engine related and only noticeable with certain speeds. If you make it slower - it's all smooth. You can see the same stuttering if you use transitions instead of moving it manaully on enterFrame:

```
local ooo = display.newImage("obj.png")
ooo.y = display.contentCenterY - 100
local function doAgain()
    transition.to(ooo, {time=2000, x=display.contentWidth, onComplete=function()
        ooo.x = 0
        doAgain()
    end})
end
doAgain()
```

Try contacting Ansca stuff if you think this is critical. But I wouldn't notice that if you didn't mention.